# using for loop tag in tab nav bootstrap with django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem using the for loop tag, It is fine for tabs but the reference for id in tab content itself is the problem as I can't access the instant value of in {{spec}} and now How can I customize my url with nav pills tabs to show the courses related to specializations,

## category_page.html

```
<!-- This is tabs with for loop for data in specializations worked well-->
     <div class="row" >
                <div class="list-group col-md-4" role="navigation">
                  {% for specs in spec %}
                        <button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab" href="{{ specs }}">{{ specs }}</button>

                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
<!-- Here is the tab content and it doesn't work well as I need data appears related to the tab itself --> 
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="tab-content ">
                        {% for specs in spec %}
                    <div id="{{ specs }}" class="tab-pane fade ">
                            <div class="row">
                                {% for instances in courses_spec %}
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                          <div class="caption">
                                            <h3>{{ instances.name }}</h3>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>

                                {% endfor %}


                    </div>
                </div>
```

## views.py

```
def categories_pages(request, category_name, speci_name=None):
    courses = Course_dir.objects.filter(
        availability=True,
        id_CO__id_S__name=category_name
    ).order_by('date')

    courses_spec = Course_dir.objects.filter(
        availability=True,
        id_CO__name=speci_name
    ).order_by('date')

    spec = Specialization.objects.filter(
        id_S__name__contains=category_name
    ).order_by('name')
    context = {
        "courses": courses,
        "spec": spec,
        "courses_spec": courses_spec
    }
    return render(request, 'categories/categories-page.html', context)
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^categories/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.categories_pages, name='category_detail'),
url(r'^categories/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<speci_name>[-\w]+)$', views.categories_pages, name='specialization_detail'),
```

## models.py

```
 class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=None)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    return reverse('category_detail', args=[str(self.slug)])

class Specialization(models.Model):
    id_S = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
slug = models.SlugField(default=None)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    return reverse('spec_detail', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things -

1. You aren't calling `get_absolute_url` anywhere, so the template will only display the return value of the model's `__unicode__` method (if Python 2) or `__str__` method (if Python 3).
2. Don't call `for spec in spec`, use separate variables so there isn't namespace pollution and potential errors.

   `{% for each_spec in spec %}
       <button type="button" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="tab" 
               href="{{ each_spec.get_absolute_url }}">{{ spec }}</button>
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: I know this and it is done , but it is not my problem , my problem that the nav pill hyperlink can't resolve its tab to open it